# How to intercept REQUEST correctly

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I've set up an interceptor class to add jwt token to request headers but the requests are still without token.

I've set up the class and put a `console.log` before the call to `request.clone` to see if my token is really there. But it seems like it isn't passed to the request:

```
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
        constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

        intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
                // add authorization header with jwt token if available
                let currentUser = this.authenticationService.currentUserValue;
                let currentToken = this.authenticationService.currentTokenValue;

                if (currentUser && currentToken) {
                    console.log(currentToken);

                    const cloned = request.clone({
                                setHeaders: {
                                        Authorization: `Bearer ${currentToken}`
                                }
                        });
                }

                return next.handle(request);
        }
}
```

`console.log` shows the token.

My service function:

```
export class UserService {
        constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

        getAll() {
                return this.http.get<User[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}/users`);
        }
}
```

The request is made after success logging. I do a redirection to the home page and the ngInit call this method.

I expect to do the request with the token in the header but It's not passed through (sorry for my English).

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you create `cloned` and did nothing with it. return it.

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    // ... yada yada yada ...
      if ... {
        return request.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${currentToken}` } });
      }
      return next.handle(request);   
}
```

Comment: sorry for wasting your time for little things like this. Thank you for your help. It's good right now